# I would like to set 127.0.0.1 in my resolv.conf

Tags: browser, localhost, resolv.conf

I was hoping to set my local host in my resolv.conf to hermes. So in affect if I type in hermes:8080 into the browser, I get the localhost:8080

How is this accomplished?

Please and thank you.

Comment: From what I understand reading the answers, you need to replace 'localhosts' in '/etc/hosts' with 'hermes'. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

You need it in `/etc/hosts`, not `/etc/resolv.conf`.

And your host name should already appear in `/etc/hosts`.

What does it say when you run this from the terminal?

```
grep '127.0.1.1' /etc/hosts
```

What about:

```
cat /etc/hostname
```

Comment: what do I need to do to get the desired result. it says hermes. to answer your first question. hermes as well for your second question.

Answer (score 1):

You can add it to /etc/hosts, like this:

127.0.0.1 hermes

(127.0.0.1 is the same as localhost)

Comment: That's bad.  If you replace the `127.0.0.1` entry, things will break.  It should be added using a separate entry `127.0.1.1 hermes`, but it should have already been added by NetworkManager, so there is another problem.

Comment: Adding it won't break anything, because it doesn't overwrite previous links to 127.0.1.1.

Comment: There is a difference between `127.0.0.1` and `127.0.1.1`.  You said `127.0.0.1`, which should just be `127.0.0.1 localhost` (or `127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost` or similar).

Comment: If you add a second `127.0.0.1` entry, then some things will work, but reverse lookups (e.g. `getent hosts 127.0.0.1`) won't return your host name, which could break some things.

Comment: I've got multiple things going to 127.0.0.1 in my /etc/hosts: http://i.imgur.com/A2aCj.png

Comment: @Mikel this is what I need. I would like 127.0.0.1 to also to respond to hermes. How can I achieve this?